# Прилагательное как часть сказуемого

Tags: прилагательные, тип-сказуемого, сравнительная-степень

Разве может прилагательное в форме простой сравнительной степени быть частью сказуемого в предложении, в котором нет подлежащего?
Прилагательное же характеризует грамматический предмет. Как тогда объяснить данный пример? Разве так бывает?

*Вам нужно быть **послушнее.***

Comment: Хм. Тут неясно, с какого боку отвечать. Про безличные предложения, предикативы, составные именные сказумые знаете?

Comment: Попробуйте по сути ответить. Тут явное прилагательное:  быть более послушными. Понятно, что это сказуемое, понятно, что сказуемое в паре с модальным словом, однако разве такое бывает?

Comment: Если бы не было, откуда бы вы взяли пример?

Comment: Ни в одном учебнике не видел, чтобы было написано о том, что прилагательное в сравнительное степени может быть сказуемым в безличном  предложении. Об этом и был вопрос.

Comment: Можете рассказать, какие уже читали?

Comment: Я имею в виду школьные учебники. Я вопрос задаю в рамках школьного курса РЯ.

Comment: Глубоко уважаю ваш интерес, но в школе это изучают по минимуму. Составное именное сказуемое - потенциально многочленная конструкция: склоняемый глагол/связка, предикатив, зависимые инфинитивы, именная часть (сущ., прил., прич., нар., числ., идиома). Я хотел начать петь красивее. Нужно стремиться быть добрее. Почему вы видите ограничение именно на сравнит.степень?

Comment: Всегда прописывается в учебниках, что прил. в ср. степени является сказуемым в двусоставном предложении.

Comment: Если вы это знаете, как тогда возник ваш вопрос из поста? "Разве может прилагательное в форме простой сравнительной степени быть частью сказуемого".

Comment: Вопрос именно о безличных предложениях (" в которых нет подлежащего", именно в этом и есть вопрос)

Comment: Тема нешкольная - про безличные глаголы (основа для сказуемого в безличных пред.). У них только одно общее - не разрешают подлежащее в именит. падеже. Но по семантике они совсем разные. Многие из них сочетаются с субъектами, которые называют "неканоническое подлежащее", и эти субъекты вполне можно описать сравнит.степенью прилагательного. Глагол "вечереть" - тотально безличный, никаких прилагательных не допустит. Но есть и другие "Мне нужно быть умнее". Мне - это и есть "неканоническое подлежащее" (член предложения с подлежащными свойствами). Именительного падежа нет, а субъект-то есть.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, "мне" и подобные местоимения не могут вообще быть подлежащими.

Comment: Они не могут быть каноническими подлежащими. Но кое-какие подлежащные свойства у них есть и именно они дают вам объяснение, что тут делает сравнительная степень.

Comment: Исключение, значит?

Comment: Исключение - это термин для школ, таблиц, справочников, так проще запоминать) В языке исключений нет, есть разные формы в сложной системе. Которая никогда не втискивается полностью в схему, созданную человеком. Спасибо за беседу!